# Excel VBA Function runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error Pin

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need help please! I have no experience in programming or whatsoever and I     have been sent this excel file to execute macros. But somehow it doesn't work and the message

> Excel VBA Function runtime error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined Error

keeps appearing. I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it.

```
Columns("A:A").Select 
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
     TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
     Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, _
     OtherChar:="<", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
     TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Above is the highlighted part. Is there something wrong with the coding? Or is it because the file was created on non-Mac laptop and I am using Mac?

Please help, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Are you supposed to fix it? Send the file back quoting the problem asking whoever authored the spreadsheet to fix it. This is a site for programmers, if you don't know how to code it's going to be very difficult to help you solve this.

Answer (score -1):

I have observed that the `"TrailingMinusNumbers:=True"` statement in the Text to Columns code will cause a 1004 error when run on a Mac (running Office 2013 Excel). To test this issue, I designed a simple test where two Text to Columns macros were created in the same workbook in Windows 7. One included the `"TrailingMinusNumbers:=True"` statement. The other did not. Both macros ran fine on the Windows platform, but when the macros were run on the Mac platform, the macro with the `"TrailingMinusNumbers:=True"` statement failed (error 1004). The macro without this statement ran OK.